# How to return the record from an access query

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I am currently completing a project where a series of combo boxes will hopefully link back to a single database record I will take in 5 values and I have the following code how do I output the records it has returned so I can use the values found in the table have not been entered by the user, in a later part of the code?

```
 myConnection.ConnectionString = My.Forms.Main.connString
 myConnection.Open()
 Dim match As String = "SELECT CBrand, CModel, CSpec,BodyStyle,CNoOfDoors, CEngineSize, COTR, TransmissionCost 
 FROM CarFigures WHERE CBrand = cbBrand.text
 CModel  = cbModel.text
 CSpec = cbSpec.text 
 CNoOfDoors = cbNoOfDoors.text
 EngineSize = cbEngineSize.text"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you open a connection and have your query you need to do this:

```
myConnection.ConnectionString = My.Forms.Main.connString
myConnection.Open()
Dim match As String = "SELECT CBrand, CModel, ..."

' define data adapter, data set, fill data set then loop'
Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim ds As New Dataset
Dim row As System.Data.DataRow
Dim count As Integer
da.SelectCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(match, myConnection)
da.Fill(ds, "myTable") 
count = ds.Tables("myTable").Rows.Count

While count > -1
    row = ds.Tables("myTable").Rows.Item(count)
    ' this is where you take row.Item(0) and do something with it... '
    count = count - 1
End While

myConnection.Close()
```

Comment: thanks, sorry I'm still learning the basics with vb and I was just wondering where the ... is on the third line do I put the where sql command from my code in there and do I need to name the table in "mytable"??

Comment: not sure which line you refer to as third; you can name your table whatever

Comment: If my answer has helped you please consider upvoting / accepting an answer

Comment: where it says 'dim match as string = "select...." do I write the select and from part of the sql command or do I just write the select part of the query

Comment: You would write the whole thing - `SELECT x FROM t WHERE t.x >0`, etc. I guess you could grab a larger dataset and filter it out in a `WHILE` loop, but that really is not very efficient.